# SpringBoot, how to Authenticate with LDAP without using ldif?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying out the LDAP Authentication example in SpringBoot [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

It is using the ldif approach which I think is not applicable to my requirements because our ldap admin wont tell me where to find the ldif that I need.
Before springboot I used to use my own ldap implementation not using ldif.  Is there a way to validate not using ldif just the SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION.simple ?
Below is how I do ldap security in basic Java no spring.  How do I do this in spring without using ldif just basic username password.

```
boolean isLdapRegistred(String username, String password) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.x.x.x:389");           
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");         
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "OUR-DOMAIN\\" + username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        // Create the initial context
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        result = ctx != null;
        if (ctx != null)
        ctx.close();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("oops");
        return result;
    }

}
```

Below is SpringBoots example need to use my credentials instead of ldif.

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.contextSource().url("ldap://10.x.x.x").port("389")` instead of `.contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");`?

Comment: FYI, @jny, the input parameter for the `port()` method is an int, not a String.

Answer (score 7):

this one has worked perfectly for me but I need to make tiny modifications to it.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
Arrays.asList("ldapServerUrl:port"),rootDn);
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
            LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(ldapUserSearchBase, ldapUserSearchFilter, contextSource);
            BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
            bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch);
            LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator, new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, ldapGroupSearchBase));
            return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
        }
    }
```

I have suffered for days before getting to this point
Other wise you can use custom authentication and make the like this

```
    @Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String email = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        log.info("email : " + email);
        log.info("password : " + password);

        try {
            if (authenticate(email, password)) {

                // use the credentials
                // and authenticate against the third-party system
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        email, password, new ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            log.info(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean isLdapRegistred(String username, String password) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.x.x.x:389");           
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");         
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "OUR-DOMAIN\\" + username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        // Create the initial context
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        result = ctx != null;
        if (ctx != null)
        ctx.close();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("oops");
        return result;
    }

}


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

and on another class

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Then the magic happens

Comment: thanks, worked for me changing "if (authenticate(email, password)) " to "(isLdapRegistred(email, password))"

Answer (score 6):

Without LDIF, and using Spring, you can do something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapServerUrl);
        contextSource.setUserDn(ldapManagerDn);
        contextSource.setPassword(ldapManagerPassword);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(ldapUserSearchBase, ldapUserSearchFilter, contextSource);
        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch);
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator, new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, ldapGroupSearchBase));
        return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without **ldif** you can use like this:

1. Add below parameter to the `application.properties`:

```
ad.domain=domain.name
ad.url=ldap://url:port
```

2. Create securityconfig class extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like this:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
    
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;
    
    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String AD_URL;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest()
             .fullyAuthenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. I mean, if the username and password are wrong, you get this warning back by spring boot itself.

```
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
```

If you type it correctly, it's up to you which page you redirect to.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

in case somebody is interested in corresponding Spring Boot configuration, this is what worked for me (i tried to remove irrelevant details):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://hostname:389/dc=myapp,dc=mycompany,dc=com")
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},cn=Users");
    }
}
```

the above code corresponds to the following ldapsearch command (they often suggest to use ldapsearch to tryout different path configurations for base DN and userDnPatterns:

```
ldapsearch -H "ldap://hostname:389" -D "cn=someuser,cn=Users,dc=myapp,dc=mycompany,dc=com" -W -b "dc=myapp,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 'cn=someuser,cn=Users,dc=myapp,dc=mycompany,dc=com'
```

- -W asks for password interactively
- -H specifies host:port
- -D cn - instructs ldapsearch to bind specifically to this address (cn) - as far as i understood, this corresponds to logging into LDAP with this CN, as far as the password given to the following prompt is alright
- -b ... specifies base DN that will filter the results
- it is very important to not forget the last part in single quotes above (single or double i don't think this makes any difference) because this specifies the query that ldapsearch will execute after binding/logging in - if you don't specify anything, it will try to perform search of ALL entries and may render LDAP server unresponsive

and finally, {0} in Spring Boot security config is where "someuser" from ldapsearch goes, i.e. Spring will construct the address to bind to from what is given in userDnPatterns, replacing {0} with whatever username is specified during login

PS. this worked with an older version of Oracle Internet Directory, where all users we wanted to authenticate were under cn=Users instead of e.g. ou=people in the corresponding Spring Boot LDAP tutorial (i guess)