# Login form user credentials instead of hard-coded UserDn and Password in LDAP Spring Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I have implemented the spring security with LDAP using Spring Boot. I'm able to successfully bind with my company LDAP server but with hard-coded values. This is the only way I can bind with my company LDAP server and proceed further since I do not know the Administrator/Generic UserDN or Password to make a successful bind. The company does not provide me the Admin credentials due to some confidential reasons.

I would like to **set the UserDn and Password of the ContextSource with the username and password entered by the user in the login form**. But the problem here is the SecurityConfig class is scanned at the time the Tomcat server is started and later after the login process the control does not come to the SecurityConfig class at all. How can I solve this problem? Need some assistance.

This is my **SecurityConfig** class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/sign-in")
                .usernameParameter("userid")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(customAuthSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(customAuthFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthProvider());

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider() throws Exception {

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldaps://some.domain.com:3269/");
        contextSource.setUserDn("username@domain.com"); // Here I want to set the username from Login screen
        contextSource.setPassword("password"); // also password from login screen
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        String userSearchFilter = "(sAMAccountName=username)"; // Here too I need to set username from login screen
        LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("dc=domain,dc=com", userSearchFilter, contextSource);
        BindAuthenticator bindAuth = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuth.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch);
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuth);

        return ldapAuthProvider;
    }
}
```

I have created an AuthenticationProvider bean method and I'm setting it in the AuthenticationManagerBuilder. I also tried creating a **CustomAuthenticationProvider** but there again I had to check with the hard-coded username and password :(

Comment: Hi, think this should help `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })`

Comment: Hi @Jayesh, Adding this will disable Spring Security right? WIll this then serve the purpose of not setting Hard-coded values in SecurityConfig class? I'm new to SpringBoot hence a bit sceptical about it.

Comment: Anyways I tried excluding SecurityAutoConfig and I got an exception while starting tomcat. It said SecurityConfig Bean could not be initialized.. some dependency error regarding ObjectPostProcessor bean

Comment: Have you created your own bean for security? My code snippet will only prevent auto config to create a default config for you.

Comment: No I haven't, I'm using spring security and trying to use LDAP to allow colleagues to login to the application using their company LDAP crendentials

Comment: In that case, I think I won't be able to help you further as I have limited knowledge in this. Sorry for not being of much help.

Comment: Should I remove the authenticationProvider and perform the authentication part in some other class other than Security config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working.. :) I found what I want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732689/springboot-how-to-authenticate-with-ldap-without-using-ldif) . (Ali Miskeen's answer)

I tried with the **CustomAuthenticationProvider** approach itself but this time, I checked for authentication using the traditional JNDI LDAP approach. I also wanted to check for 3 different LDAP servers hence this approach best suited for my application.

Here is my complete CustomAuthenticationProvider implementation:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String AT_DOMAIN_COM = "@domain.com";

    private static final String SINGLE_SPACE = " ";

    @Value("${ldap.url.for.server1}")
    private String ldapUrlForServer1; // url set in application.properties

    @Value("${ldap.url.for.server2}")
    private String ldapUrlForServer2;

    @Value("${ldap.url.for.server3}")
    private String ldapUrlForServer3;

    @Value("${ldap.jndi.context.factory}")
    private String ldapContextFactory;

    @Value("${ldap.authentication.type}")
    private String ldapAuthenticationType; // auth type is "simple"

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();

        if (isLdapRegisteredUser(username, password)) {
            // use the credentials and authenticate against a third-party system
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    boolean isLdapRegisteredUser(String username, String password) {

        boolean result = false;
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        LdapContext ctx = null;

        try {

            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ldapContextFactory);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, ldapAuthenticationType);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + AT_DOMAIN_COM);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            // here I'm checking for 3 different LDAP servers
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  ldapUrlForServer1 + SINGLE_SPACE + ldapUrlForServer2 + SINGLE_SPACE + ldapUrlForServer3); 

            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

            if (ctx != null) {
                result = true;
                String selectedLdapUrl = ctx.getEnvironment().get(Context.PROVIDER_URL).toString();
                // do further operations with "ctx" if needed
                System.out.println("selected LDAP url is: " + selectedLdapUrl);
                System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
            }

        } catch(NamingException nex) {
            nex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        return result;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

And here is my SecurityConfig implementation:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/sign-in")
                .usernameParameter("userid")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(customAuthSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(customAuthFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps :) Happy coding...